# Anyone used flutter google login and onesignal with same app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, onesignal

my packages:

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
scoped_model: "^0.3.0"
http: ^0.12.0+2
lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.0.0
sqflite: any
path_provider: any
icon_shadow: ^1.0.1
flutter_responsive_screen: ^1.0.0
shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
connectivity: ^0.4.3+6
flutter_range_slider: ^1.3.1
image_cropper: ^1.0.2
image_picker: ^0.6.1+3
url_launcher: ^5.1.2
rich_alert: ^0.1.32
flutter_svg: ^0.14.1
google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
date_picker_timeline: ^0.0.3
smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.3
date_format: ^1.0.6
flutter_google_places: ^0.2.3
flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
onesignal_flutter: ^2.1.0
```

This is my pubspec.yaml 
normally if i initiate onesignal function it's getting below error, i think problem with both firebase_auth and onesignal_flutter plugins google services clashes, can anyone face this type of issue?

But am getting the onesingal token after that app crash getting below error.

Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.seek-Aq7q4Ly6HVEDPPreJQc1zQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
I/zygote64(30113):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (VMClassLoader.java:-2)